# Bipolar transistor amplification biased

Tags: transistors, bjt

This exercise is about a BJT transistor common emitter circuit, with a biasing resistor between the base and the collector. I am supposed to compute the signal amplification of the circuit \$V_o/V_s\$ (\$V_o\$ being at node1). I am given that the transistor has \$\beta = 50\$ and \$r_{\pi} = 1.1\$ for the \$\pi\$ equivalent model.
 [image]

Comment: What work have you done so far? Also, your value of \$r_{\pi}\$ seems low. Is that supposed to be in k\$\Omega\$?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry it is. I have drown the equivalent circuit with the pi model i just don't know where to put Rb, as part of the input or output?

Comment: Do you have some knowledge about negative feedback?

Comment: not really, i am a second year student, just getting started with electronic

Comment: General: Pi model would need dragging out of memory and dusting off but this is general approach: Assume Z_AC source = 0 for DC. For model used, establish DC operating point. Establish Rbe internal from current.Solve.

Comment: For DC operating point we need the supply voltage. On the other hand - beta and r,pi is given, hence we don`t need the Q point.

Answer (score 2):

There are, in principle, two ways for solving the task. Please understand that I do not intent to present the solution for you. However, I will try to give you some hints to find the solution by yourself.

**1.) Application of the superposition theorem**

Supplementing the transistor Pi-model with the external resistors results in a circuit which contains two sources: A voltage source Vin and the controlled current source of the Pi-model. Thus, after applying the superposition principle you get two equations for finding the two unknown quantities: **Vo/Vin** and **Vbe**. (Please note that the transconductance of the Pi-model can be expressed by the two known values for beta and Rpi).

**2.) Application of the general gain formula for negative feedback**

The closed-loop gain is **Vo/Vin=Acl=AoHf/(1-AoHr)**. (Note that Ao will be negative).

Gain without feedback **Ao=Vout/V(base)** (simple gain formula for common emitter);

Forward (damping)factor **Hf=V(base)/Vin** for Vout=0;

Return (feedback) factor **Hr=V(base)/Vout** for Vin=0.

Both factors are calculated using simple voltage divider rules.

Comment: This transistor circuit exploits the same idea (parallel negative feedback) as the op-amp inverting amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the Rb and connect it directly between the base and VC and denote it as Rb+Rc. Then the circuit simplifies a great deal and then you can use the two variable method specified by LvW.